# Passing on kwargs to complex functions

Tags: python, python-3.5, mypy, type-hinting

Consider the following attempt at add adding type hints to the functions `parent` and `child`:

```
def parent(*, a: Type1, b: Type2):
    ...

def child(*, c: Type3, d: Type4, **kwargs):
    parent(**kwargs)
    ...
```

MyPy complains that `kwargs` has the type `Dict[str, Any]` but that the arguments `a` and `b` require `Type1` and `Type2` respectively.

I understand that the solution to this error is to rewrite `child` in the following way:

```
def child(*, a: Type1, b: Type2, c: Type3, d: Type4, **kwargs):
    parent(a=a, b=b)
    ...
```

However, what if the argument list of `parent` is **much** longer, or there is function `grandchild` which has its own argument list and must call `child`. Are you required to enumerate the arguments and their types from all the downstream functions? Or is there a graceful way to handle the "per-key" typing of `**kwargs`?

Comment: This has been posted to MyPy on GitHub too: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6552

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the advent of `TypedDict` in [PEP-692](https://peps.python.org/pep-0692/) this has technically been solved:

```py
class ParentKwargs(TypedDict):
    a: Type1
    b: Type2

def parent(**kwargs: Unpack[ParentKwargs]):
    ...

class ChildKwargs(ParentKwargs):
    c: Type3
    d: Type4

def child(**kwargs: Unpack[ChildKwargs]):
    ...
```

Though perhaps not in an entirely ideal fashion - you now have to destructure the kwargs to use them and dealing with default values isn't pretty:

```py
class ParentKwargs(TypedDict):
    a: Type1
    b: Type2

def parent(**kwargs: Unpack[ParentKwargs]):
    a = kwargs["a"]
    b = kwargs["b"]


class OptionalChildKwargs(TypedDict, total=False):
    c: Type3

class ChildKwargs(OptionalChildKwargs, ParentKwargs):
    d: Type4

def child(**kwargs: Unpack[ChildKwargs]):
    c = kwargs.get(default_value)
    d = kwargs["d"]
```

At this point there's so much visual noise that it would probably be better to just enumerate all the kwargs as you would have needed to to absent `TypedDict`.

Answer (score 0):

mypy now supports annotating **kwargs using Unpack + TypedDict, as per PEP 692: https://peps.python.org/pep-0692/

Comment: Thanks. IMO `TypedDict` does technically solve the problem, though perhaps not in an entirely satisfactory manner: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77823662/3159288